# Can I make dua for rizk (provisions) in sujood after glorifying Allah?

Tags: salat, dua

I am a person who sometimes get tested by Allah in the form of lack of rizk. I am repenting and I would like to know that can I dua in sujood for rizk after glorifying Allah in Arabic?

Comment: Please consider elaborating your question. Usually you can do du'a any time during sujud in prayer you also can do du'a at any time of the day without sujud.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu alaikum,

And We will surely test you with something of fear and hunger and a loss of wealth and lives and fruits, but give good tidings to the patient
[2:155]
So have patience which is so tough but you will get reward by The Almighty in sha ALLAH. In one hadith it mentioned that
“The closest that a servant is to his Lord is when he is in prostration.” (Muslim)
In another hadith 
 Rabi'a b. Ka'b said:I was with Allah’s Messenger ﷺ one night and I brought him water and what he required.

He said to me: ‘Ask [anything you like].’

I said: ‘I ask your company in Paradise.’

He said: ‘Anything else besides it?’

I said: ‘That is all (that I require).’

He said: ‘Then help me to achieve this for you by devoting yourself often to prostration.’” (Muslim)
So ask Allah whatever you want in sujood. In sha Allah you will get what you want. :)

Comment: prostrating often in the last hadith refers to night prayer so the Prophet pbuh recommended to perform many rak'at of optional prayers at night.